# Is there a way to import environment variables in cloud foundry application from a file

Tags: json, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

There is an option to set Environment variables in cloud foundry application in a runtime section. It also has an option to export these user defined variables to a JSON file.
Is there a way to import them from a JSON file in bulk, or should i always create them manually one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cloud Foundry CLI has commands `cf set-running-environment-variable-group` and `cf set-staging-environment-variable-group` which let you set the environment from a JSON file.

http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/set-running-environment-variable-group.html

You could also script setting your environment variables by using the `cf set-env` command from the CLI.